# How can I manually decrypt content encrypted by infoencrypt.com (AES-128)?

Tags: encryption, md5

TLDR: I need to decrypt AES-128 plain text encrypted by the now-defunct site Infoencrypt.com. I have the unhashed passphrase-like keys. My files all follow this format and spec:

```
-----BEGIN INFOENCRYPT.COM MESSAGE-----
Encryption-Info: AES-128,CBC,PKCS5 Padding
Key-Info: MD5,PBKDF2 HmacSHA1
Decrypt-URL: https://www.infoencrypt.com

[ENCRYPTED STUFF]
-----END INFOENCRYPT.COM MESSAGE-----
```

What's the best way to do this?

I've never directly touched encryption before. I'm guessing I will need to first hash and pad my keys but am not sure where to start.

I'd prefer to set this up locally on my machine for future proofing but am open to online tools as long as they run entirely client-side (as Infoencrypt.com used to).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the github repo: https://github.com/jpelias/botverde

Open the index.html file and you should be able to do it

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! That repo contains the full infoencrypt.com website.